# No Inheritance is occuring in the angularJS code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is an AngularJS inheritance code where the inheritance is applied in the functions but there is no output coming for this code.
custDetails and empPaycheck are the two functions where inheritance is applied but the code has some error which I am not been able to find.

```
 <html lang="">

<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Controller Inheritance</title>

        <script src="angulaar.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module("sample",
        []).run(["$rootScope",function($rootScope){
        $rootScope.taxPe`enter code here`rcent = 30;
        }]);

        app.controller("custDetails", ["$scope",function($scope) {
            $scope.Name = "Dipanshu";
            $scope.Sal = 45000;
            $scope.Dept = "Testing";
        }]);

        app.controller("empPayCheck", ["$scope", "$rootScope",    
            function($scope, $rootScope) {
            $scope.getTaxes = function() {
            return $scope.Sal * $rootScope.taxPercent / 100;
            };

        $scope.getNet = function() {
            return $scope.Sal - $scope.getTaxes();
        };
    }]);
</script>

</head>

    <body ng-app="sample">
        <div ng-controller="custDetails">
            Employee Details of {{Name}}

        <div ng-controller="custDetails">
                {{Name}} earns {{Sal}} rs and is in <strong>{{Dept}}</strong>
                Department.

            <div controller="empPayCheck">
                Tax: {{getTaxes()}}
                <br> Net Amount: {{getNet()}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is error in your `module` run block near `$rootScope.taxPe`;
2. You are using `controller` attribute instead of [`ng-controller`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController).

Here is a working code snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module("sample", []).run(["$rootScope", function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.taxPercent = 30;
}]);

app.controller("custDetails", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.Name = "Dipanshu";
  $scope.Sal = 45000;
  $scope.Dept = "Testing";
}]);

app.controller("empPayCheck", ["$scope", "$rootScope",
  function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.getTaxes = function() {
      return $scope.Sal * $rootScope.taxPercent / 100;
    };

    $scope.getNet = function() {
      return $scope.Sal - $scope.getTaxes();
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="sample">
  <div ng-controller="custDetails">
    Employee Details of {{Name}}

    <div ng-controller="custDetails">
      {{Name}} earns {{Sal}} rs and is in <strong>{{Dept}}</strong> Department.

      <div ng-controller="empPayCheck">
        Tax: {{getTaxes()}}
        <br> Net Amount: {{getNet()}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**P.S.**: Personally I would [not recommend using `$rootScope`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761540/why-using-rootscope-with-functions-is-not-recommended) and scope inheritance, you can use [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) to share data between controllers. Also would suggest you looking into [`component`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) API that comes in v1.5+.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$scope.$parent` to access parent `$scope` variables in a child controller.
Also in your HTML code there's a typo where `controller` should be `ng-controller`.
Look at the following working example.

```js
var app = angular.module("sample", []).run(["$rootScope", function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.taxPercent = 30;
}]);

app.controller("custDetails", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.Name = "Dipanshu";
  $scope.Sal = 45000;
  $scope.Dept = "Testing";
}]);

app.controller("empPayCheck", ["$scope", "$rootScope",
  function($scope, $rootScope) {
      
    $scope.getTaxes = function() {
      return $scope.$parent.Sal * $rootScope.taxPercent / 100;
    };

    $scope.getNet = function() {
      return $scope.$parent.Sal - $scope.getTaxes();
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="sample">
  <div ng-controller="custDetails">
    Employee Details of {{Name}}

    <div>
      {{Name}} earns {{Sal}} rs and is in <strong>{{Dept}}</strong> Department.

      <div ng-controller="empPayCheck">
        Tax: {{getTaxes()}}
        <br> Net Amount: {{getNet()}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy @Thusitha

Comment: @Dipanshu Glad to help you. You can mark it as the correct answer ;)