# Change the colour of the Progress-bar in between if a process gives some error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am new to `angularjs` . I am using  `progress-bar`. So, Here

I have a upload functionality where user can upload many files.In that to show progress I am using the `progressBar`. So, My code for the progress bar is like -

```
<uib-progressbar
  class="progress-striped active"
                    ng-show="folderProcessing && !isSingleFile"
                    animate="true" max="100"
                    value="progressValuePercentage"
                    type="success">
                    <i>
                        <span>
                            {{progressValuePercentage}} / 100
                        </span>
                    </i>
```

So here In controller ,

```
 if (($rootScope.progressValue !== $rootScope.totalFiles)) {
                $rootScope.folderProcessing = true;
                $rootScope.progressValue = $rootScope.progressValue + 1;
                $rootScope.progressValuePercentage = (($rootScope.progressValue * 100) / $rootScope.totalFiles).toFixed(2);
                if ($scope.progressValue === $rootScope.totalFiles) {
                  $rootScope.progressValue = 0;
                  $rootScope.progressValuePercentage = 0;

                }
              }
```

Now

```
if (docType === AppConstants.docType.RESUME) {
                if(res.isProcessedSuccessfully) {
                  toastr.success(AppConstants.fileProcessSuccessMessage, 'File processed successfully');
                } else {

                  toastr.error(res.documentId, 'File Processing Failed');
                }
             } else {
                $rootScope.folderProcessing = false;
                toastr.success(AppConstants.jobDescriptionSuccessMessage, 'File processed successfully');
                $scope.hideProcessSpinner =  true;
              }
```

Now when there is an error like toaster.error then  if 50% is completed then after that if error is there then it should take the next portion in `red` colour and the if next one processed successfully then should fill the portion in `green` its original colour. How can I achieve this ? Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: (_Additionally_) [You shouldn't pollute your `$rootScope`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761540/why-using-rootscope-with-functions-is-not-recommended). Instead bind your variables to `$scope` or create a Service/Factory for your logic/processing to [share the data between your controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use the angular ng-class directive to handle color changes.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

just create classes for the color changes you need then apply then through the directive with your logic as to when it should show.